# Get identity value before saving in JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I have a database with an auto-generated primary key. The corresponding JPA entry is below:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
@JsonProperty("item_id")
private Long id;
```

Now, I have another String field to which I need to append the id before inserting it into the DB. Is it possible to get the identity value before inserting the value into the database? I saw on some posts that I can flush the entity. But I'm not sure if that would work in my scenario. I'm new to JPA, so I don't know the effects of doing a flush.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you can't, because each DBMS has its own strategy to generate unique IDs. What you can do is [1] create the object first and then update the value based on the generated id in the same transaction or [2] generating the unique ID in the application, using something like UUID

Comment: An id is guaranteed to be generated at flush time (`EntityManager#flush()`). If this does not happen, then your code is likely not doing what it is supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. The generated key comes back from DB as part of the statement doing the INSERT operation. Even the retrieval of the generated keys is implementation-specific and is not guaranteed on every storage.